# Automatic Token refreshing in laravel10 using refresh_token

Tags: php, laravel, passport.js, middleware, laravel-10

I have created one middleware following is its code

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        $accessToken = $request->bearerToken();

        if (!$accessToken) {
            $oClient = PassportClient::where('password_client', 1)->firstOrFail();
            $refreshToken = $request->cookie('refreshToken');

            if ($refreshToken) {
                $serverUrl = Config::get('contants.PROJURL');
                $tokenRequest = Request::create($serverUrl . '/oauth/token', 'post', [
                    'grant_type' => 'refresh_token',
                    'refresh_token' => $refreshToken,
                    'client_id' => $oClient->id,
                    'client_secret' => $oClient->secret,
                    'scope' => '',
                ]);
                $response = app()->handle($tokenRequest);

                if ($response->getStatusCode() == 200) {
                    $content = json_decode($response->getContent(), true);
                    $token = $content['access_token'];
                    $refreshToken = $content['refresh_token'];

                    // Now set the new access token for the current request
                    $request->headers->set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $token);

                    // Continue the request
                    $response = $next($request);

                    // Attach the new tokens to the response
                    return $response->cookie('token', $token, 1) // Adjust the expiry time as needed
                        ->cookie('refreshToken', $refreshToken, 10080); // Adjust the expiry time as needed
                } else {
                    // Log the error or handle the response as appropriate
                    Log::error('Failed to refresh token: ' . $response->getContent());
                    return response()->json([
                        'status' => 'error',
                        'message' => 'Refresh token failed.',
                    ], $response->getStatusCode());
                }
            } else {
                // Handle the case where no refresh token is present
                return response()->json([
                    'status' => 'error',
                    'message' => 'No refresh token provided.',
                ], 401);
            }
        }

        // Proceed with the request if there is an access token present
        return $next($request);
    }
```

Now this code is not working properly. Response is getting set properly using cookie but request bearer token is not updating. api call that executed after execution of this middleware contains refresh_token instead of token. I dont know how it is happening.  I have done prioritization of middleware

```
protected $middlewarePriority = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\RefreshTokenMiddleware::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckUserRole::class,
    ];
```

Please help me out. I have kept expiry time of access token as 1 minute just for quick testing.

Comment: I want to auto refresh access token if it expire after 1 minute. using refresh token for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem lies in the subsequent API call using the old bearer token. This might be happening because the $request object passed to $next($request) might not have the updated token.

```
$request->headers->set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $token);    
$response = $next($request);


$newToken = $response->headers->get('newToken');

if ($newToken) {
    $request->headers->set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $newToken);
}

// Attach the new tokens to the response as before
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Mohsin, but no success.